# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed on automate-git.py

Tags: chromium, chromium-embedded

I'm trying to compile CEF locally on my Ubuntu 20.10 machine, but my automate-git.py can't finish due to a strange error while running hooks:

```
Apply runhooks.patch in /home/user/code/chromium_git/chromium/src
    9   5   build/toolchain/win/setup_toolchain.py
    11  0   build/vs_toolchain.py
... successfully applied.
-------- Running "gclient runhooks --jobs 16" in "/home/user/code/chromium_git/chromium"...
Running hooks:   5% ( 6/101) nacltools        
________ running 'vpython src/build/download_nacl_toolchains.py --mode nacl_core_sdk sync --extract' in '/home/user/code/chromium_git/chromium'
INFO: --Syncing arm_trusted to revision 2--
INFO: Downloading package archive: emulator_arm_trusted_precise.tgz (1/1)
package_version: Could not download URL (https://storage.googleapis.com/nativeclient-archive2/toolchain/2/emulator_arm_trusted_precise.tgz): <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:727)>
Error: Command 'vpython src/build/download_nacl_toolchains.py --mode nacl_core_sdk sync --extract' returned non-zero exit status 1 in /home/user/code/chromium_git/chromium
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../automate/automate-git.py", line 1385, in <module>
    run("gclient runhooks --jobs 16", chromium_dir, depot_tools_dir)
  File "../automate/automate-git.py", line 69, in run
    return subprocess.check_call(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['gclient', 'runhooks', '--jobs', '16']' returned non-zero exit status 2.
```

On the restart it it succeeds, though, but there are compilation errors in future. I pasted `check_certificate = off` in ~/.wgetrc and `insecure` in ~/.curlrc, but no luck yet. What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by setting up a VM and compiling CEF inside it, and it all magically started working, so I guess it was my system's issue.